# setContentView method giving error in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am a newbie.
this line 
    **this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

in MainActivity.java is giving  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class ViewPager error

I was doing FragmentActivity Tutorial from CodePuppet from this [link](http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/10/06/using-fragments-in-android-with-fragmentactivity/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewPager tag is strange.

ViewPager must fill full-package and class name.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Now I am getting IndexOutofBound Exception at this line this._fragments.add(FRAGMENT_EXAMPLE, new ExampleFragment());

Comment: check the variable FRAGMENT_EXAMPLE. and ArrayList index starts zero. but code is 1